# How can I change an ng-select choice in response to a change in my model?

Tags: angularjs

I have an input field and an ng-select next to each other.  Both are backing for the same data.  As there are a large number of items in the select I can use the input field if I know the value that's needed.

But when I change the value of the input field the ng-select doesn't change until I do an update of the data in the database and retrieve data again.

When I change the value in the ng-select the value in the input field changes immediately.

Is there a way that I can get the ng-select to track changes to the underlying model and respond?

Here's the code that I have:

```
        <div class="p0r2 textAlignCenter verticalAlignTop">
            <textarea class="h1r5 pl0r3 lh1r5 resizeNone w2r"
                      ng-change="phs.phrasesStatus = Status.Dirty; row.statusId = Status.Dirty"
                      ng-model="row.categoryId"
                      maxlength="3" size="3"
                      ng-required="true"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="p0r2 textAlignCenter verticalAlignTop"
             ng-if="!phs.show">
            <select class="select"
                    convert-to-number
                    ng-change="phs.phrasesStatus = Status.Dirty; row.statusId = Status.Dirty"
                    ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in phs.phraseCategory.data"
                    ng-model="row.categoryId"></select>
        </div>
```

Here's the type of data with Typescript:

```
interface IEnumServiceGetData {
    data: IMapIdName[];
    dataPlus: IMapIdName[];
    dataMap: {};
    dataMapPlus: {}; 
    name: any;
}
interface IMapIdName {
    id: number; name: string
}
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WFbpjgf5azu3NANquC6j?p=preview Type "goo" instead of "hel", and the select updates itself. So you'll have to post a complete example in a plunkr that reproduces the problem. My guess is that convert-to-number is the culprit: the model of the textarea is a string. If it shares the model with the select, then the select's model must be a string too.

Comment: The phs.phraseCategory.data has a datatype of IMapIdName.  Not sure if that explains

Comment: Yes, it explains. If you want an input field with a number as its model use an `<input type="number">`, not a textarea.

Comment: @JBNizet - This worked thank you.  Can you propose as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: You can just accept Darin's answer, which explains the problem, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the numeric version for the id. WHen you choose a value in the input, it will be stored as a string. If the select id is a number, it will not match. Use the string version for the select ids, like this:

```
    $scope.options = [{id:"1", name:"A"},{id:"2", name:"b"},{id:"3", name:"c"}]
```